# Why is this regular expression failing?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match a string to regexp, but it is returning false when I believe it should be returning true.

```
/^★+$/ =~ '✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭' ? true : false

#irb example:
2.2.2 :001 > /^★+$/ =~ '✭' ? true : false
=> false
```

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/4qNdvC2Ap3 works for me.

Comment: Because the star in your pattern is different?

Comment: The stars are different characters (thats why they look different!)

Comment: Yeah that's how I tested it as well. Which made me very confused as to why it doesn't work in IRB

Comment: lol the patterns are different I couldn't tell! Whoever puts the answer down I will give them points. Apparently you guys have eagle eyes because they look the same to me.

Comment: Its gonna depend on the font your using

Comment: As pointed out by @CasimiretHippolyte, ` '✭'.ord #=> 10029` in the string, `'★'.ord #=> 9733` in the regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Different stars

You could accept different kind of stars :

```
/^[\*✭★☆]+$/ =~ '✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭' ? true : false
#=> true

/^[\*✭★☆]+$/ =~ "*✭✭✭★✭★✭☆☆✭★**☆*✭★✭*★★*✭★☆✭☆*★" ? true : false
#=> true
```

## object ? true : false

Note that a ternary operator which returns `true` or `false` is probably useless, because it converts truthy to `true` and falsey to `false`.

You could just use :

```
/^[\*✭★☆]+$/ =~ '✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭'
#=> 0
```

Since `0` is truthy, it wouldn't change anything for boolean logic.

## String#match?

As of Ruby 2.4, you could also use :

```
'✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭'.match? /^[\*✭★☆]+$/
#=> true
```

## String boundaries

Finally, if you want to check that the whole string is full of stars, you shouldn't use `^` or `$` but `\A` and `\z` :

```
p "✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭\nI'm not a star!!!\n✭✭✭✭✭✭".match? /^[\*✭★☆]+$/
#=> true

p "✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭\nI'm not a star!!!\n✭✭✭✭✭✭".match? /\A[\*✭★☆]+\z/
#=> false
```

Comment: In Ruby 2.4.0 you might want to use [`match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F): `'✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭✭'.match?(/^[\*✭★]+$/)`

Comment: accepted, and thanks for the heads up on the redundant ternary operator